# Apigee: Invalid Redirect URI Oauth Authentication

Tags: deployment, apigee

We are using free account of `Apigee` and facing an issue where we are getting error while doing `oauth` authentication

```
{"ErrorCode":"invalid_request","Error":"Invalid redirection uri http:\/\/dev.whodini.com:8081\/auth\/callback"}
```

Please help if somebody has faced a similar issue.

Developer App defined in Apigee has callback URL value: `http://dev.whodini.com:8081/auth/callback`

Comment: Try adjusting the URL to not use "callback". While the url parameter is reserved in the oAuth2 spec, it's also possible that Apigee is rejecting it in the URI?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestions would be to look at the 3-legged OAuth sample on Github for some pointers:

https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/tree/master/sample-proxies/oauth-authcode

One issue could be that the redirect_uri query parameter isn't in the right place on the authcode request. You can look at the sample's invoke script (invoke.sh) for working examples of each call that is made during the auth code grant type flow.

If that doesn't help, please post the requests that your app is making and we should be able to nail down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After digging deeper problem came out to be wrong client_id used to make call for this developer application. Apigee should fix the error code because it lead us in a different direction.

Comment: client_id was invalid or the redirect_uri for the client_id was? If you send a random client_id you will get invalid client_id. But in case client_id is valid but has different redirect_uri, in that case, you will receive invalid redirect_uri error"